# Set focus inside the first cell of table inserted using insertContent of a ckeditor5

Tags: focus, ckeditor5

I am setting html content received as the data of ckeditor5 using insertContent
`var content="<table style='''border:1px solid red'><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table>"; var viewFragment = editor.data.processor.toView(content); var modelFragment = editor.data.toModel(viewFragment); editor.model.insertContent(modelFragment);`

Is there a way to set the focus into the first cell of the inserted table

I have been able to set the focus on the table as a whole using -
// editor.model.insertContent(modelFragment, editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition());

But unable to focus inside the cell